# Geometric Algebra formulation of EM in nonuniform dielectric media

Tags: electromagnetism, clifford-algebra

Normally, there is a straightforward formulation of Maxwell's equations in free space under the GA framework, which reduces to (picking the right units):
$$
\nabla F = \mu_0 J
$$

with some appropriately defined bivector field $F$, some current vector $J$, and $c=1$.

Now, I've been working on several topics with non-uniform dielectric media, where I seem to lose a lot of the symmetry that is necessary in order to deal with Maxwell's equations from a GA perspective without resorting back to the original vector formulation and using the geometric algebra framework as a mostly ad-hoc method to deal with a few operations.

Are there any papers covering GA in nonuniform dielectric media? E.g. for photonic crystals or other similar applications?

Comment: It seems like this paper might help: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/the-european-physical-journal-applied-physics/article/abs/relativistic-optics-in-moving-media-with-spacetime-algebra/3F84A284F5C1E1878AA8927F1DD1D91D